# how to use 'meta_tags gem' in rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-4.2

The way I use:

```
<head>
    <title>PolymerProject</title>  
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>

    <%= set_meta_tags :description => "All text about keywords, other keywords"%>

    <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag 'custom.js', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
    <%= html_import_tag "application", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
</head>
```

the error looks like this:

```
undefined method `set_meta_tags' for #<#<Class:0x007f3ab45046c8>:0x007f3ab5144aa0><br>
```

I have installed bundle...what's problem?

Comment: tried to restart your server?

Comment: @Tom oh my god..!!thank you~

Comment: You are welcome :D I added it as an answer ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Restart your rails server.

Hope this helps.